# Blogger API: How to get posts *updated* in a particular timeframe?

Tags: python, google-api, blogger, google-api-python-client

I am working specifically with the Python Client Library, so examples are in Python.

A call to to the posts collection URI allows us to specify a `startDate` and an `endDate`. However these are applied to the *publish date*. For instance, `blogger_service.posts().list(startDate = date1, endDate = date2, orderBy = 'updated')` will fetch posts *published* between `date1` and `date2`, even though it sorts them by the update date.

My question is: How can I fetch posts *updated* between `date1` and `date2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively make a query to the publically available Feed which allows this kind of ordering. The query URL will be of the form -

```
http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?updated-min=StartDate&updated-max=EndDate&orderby=updated&alt=json
```

The accepted date format for `StartDate` and `EndDate` is ISO 8601

A working example of this endpoint is -

https://blogger.googleblog.com/feeds/posts/default?updated-min=2016-01-01T00:00:00&updated-max=2017-01-01T00:00:00&orderby=updated&alt=json